# Automate script execution

Tags: r, rstudio

Not sure how to correctly phrase this but:

Say I have a 200-line script, how can I "automate" execution such that it stops at a given line(say 50). I could do this with selection but sometimes going back and forth seems less efficient. Could there be a shortcut to this?!

Comment: Write a function?

Comment: This feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why's the automated script need to stop a specific line? Why not just remove all line after line 50? I think you may need to elaborate for people to help.

Comment: Just can't quite think of a way to do that(yet). Let's see.

Comment: @zack I'm running some models and sometimes I need to stop somewhere before I run the model. Say I close RStudio and return later, I could source the script but that would lead to the models running and a lot of time.  Manually selecting the lines works but just thought there could be a way.

Comment: You could save and load the models, using `save` and `load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no current way of doing this (though I could be very wrong here). A workaround I'd think of is using your current script in a function and using the `stop()`-function, so:

```
script <- function() {
    ...
    ...
    # when at line 50 (or whereever), use
    stop()
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: This seems fine for now. I wanted to make it stop quietly hence linking the duplicate. Would be great to have RStudio have a shortcut for this all the same.