# How to execute only a portion of already saved R script

Tags: r

I have an already saved R script, say `"analysis1.R"`. I use `source("analysis1.R")` command to run the R script when required in a different code.

How does one execute only the required lines of code?  Say first 10 lines of the code (`"analysis1.R"`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate script execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518732/automate-script-execution)

Comment: Here is a partial solution I found. Say from=1 and to=10                                                                      x = scan("analysis1.R", what = character(), sep = '\n',
                skip = from - 1, n = to - from + 1,                                                 
                 encoding = 'UTF-8', quiet = TRUE)                                                   eval.parent(parse(text=x))

Comment: For the detailed post see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214963/source-only-part-of-a-file

Answer (score 0):

```
from=1 
to=10
x = scan("analysis1.R", what = character(),
    sep = '\n', skip = from - 1, n = to - from + 1,
    encoding = 'UTF-8', quiet = TRUE) 
eval.parent(parse(text=x))
```